# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type, has no index signature

Tags: json, typescript

I have a json file that im importing from a external library in a typescript project. But when trying to access the objects in the json - `data[config.company]` I get error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ "company": { "delta": { "marketing": { "employee1": string; "employee2": string; };  has no index signature.ts(7017)
```

How do i declare the index signature here for the json data?

---

LIBRARY

myjson.json

```
{
    "company": {
        "delta": {
            "marketing": {
                "employee1": "abc999",
                "employee2": "abc777"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
import data = require('./src/myjson.json');
export {data};
```

---

MAIN PROJECT

file.ts

```
import { data } from 'project/lib';

const config = {
    company: argv.company as any | undefined || 'company',

};

const details = data[config.company];
```

Comment: The JSON pasted here under myjson.json is invalid; missing closing curly brackets, and two properties with the same name.

Comment: that was copy paste error, have fixed it. The issue is still occuring.

Comment: `const details = (data as any)[config.company];` but that sort of code is ugly.